# Segmentation fault at the end of the program

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a segmentation fault problem occurring at the very end of my program. Everything works as expected except for the sole error message. And the one appears only if I choose the second option from my menu (see menu.cpp below) which calls for one graph class method (see in Graf.cpp - "odszukaj_dfs"). After completing all tasks it exits with an above mentioned error. This means my error occurs only if during my session I use this method, hoverer just after I safely exit my session through menu option #4, regardless of what has been done in between (which menu options invoked) those two calls.

I would appreciate for any hint on what is wrong. Please let me know if you need more pieces of my code to solve it, I didn't post all of it in order not to make my post too bloated. Secondly, forgive for not using English in my code - the project is for my University and I had to stick to my native tongue. Thank you in advance.

As to what the program itself is to do - it is to read a graph from a file and be able to perform a depth-first search on it. The problem occurs while doing the latter.

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "wczytywanie_grafu/wczytaj_nazwe_pliku.h"
#include "wczytywanie_grafu/wczytaj_graf.h"
#include "menu/menu.h"
#include "graf_struktura/Graf.h"

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    using namespace std;
    const char* npliku = wczytaj_nazwe_pliku( argc, argv );
    if( npliku != 0 )
    {
        Graf *g = poprosze_graf(npliku);
        while( menu(*g) );
        delete g;
    }
    cout << "Do widzenia.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Here is where the problem occurs:

```
//menu.cpp
#include "menu.h"
#include <iostream>

  //wyswietla menu dostepnych operacji na poprawnie wczytanym grafie.
bool menu(Graf &g)
{
    using namespace std;
    int i;
    char *token;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Jaka operacje wykonac na wczytanym grafie?\n";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "1) Wyswietlic schemat.\n";
    cout << "2) Wyszukac wierzcholek metoda DFS.\n";
    cout << "3) Wczytac inny graf.\n";
    cout << "4) Opuscic program.\n";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Prosze o wybor jednej z powyzszych opcji. ";
    while( !(cin >> i) || i < 1 || i > 4 )
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
        cout << "\nBlad. Prosze podac desygnujaca odpowiedz liczbe z podanego zakresu. ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    switch( i )
    {
        case 1 :
            g.wyswietl();
            break;
        case 2 :
            cout << "Prosze podac nazwe szukanego wierzcholka. ";
            cin >> token;
            cout << "Odwiedzone wierzcholki: ";
            if( g.odszukaj_dfs(token) == 0 )
                cout << "\nNie odnaleziono wierzcholka " << token << ".\n";
            else
                cout << "\nOdnaleziono wierzcholek " << token << ".\n";
            break;
//      case 3 :
//
//          break;
        case 4 :
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here are the graph definitions ("Graf" is for graph and "Wierzcholek" for its node)

```
//Graf.cpp
#include "Graf.h"
#include "../lifo/TabDyn.h"
#include "../lifo/Stos.h"
#include <cstring>

/*###########################################################*/
/*####################### WIERZCHOLEK #######################*/
/*###########################################################*/

 /*konstruktory*/
Wierzcholek::Wierzcholek(void)
{
sasiedztwo = -1; 
nastepny = poprzedni = 0;
sasiedzi = new Wierzcholek* [1*sizeof(Wierzcholek*)];
}

Wierzcholek::Wierzcholek(char* k)
{
    klucz = k;
      //wierzcholek izolowany grafu.
    sasiedztwo = 0;
    nastepny = poprzedni = 0;
    sasiedzi = new Wierzcholek* [1*sizeof(Wierzcholek*)];
}    

Wierzcholek::Wierzcholek(char* k, int s)
{
    klucz = k; sasiedztwo = s;
    nastepny = poprzedni = 0;
      //przygotowanie tablicy sasiadow o stosownym rozmiarze
    sasiedzi = new Wierzcholek* [s*sizeof(Wierzcholek*)];
}

Wierzcholek::Wierzcholek(char* k, int s, Wierzcholek** &n)
{
      //typowy wierzcholek grafu.
    klucz = k; sasiedztwo = s; sasiedzi = n;
    nastepny = poprzedni = 0;
}

Wierzcholek::Wierzcholek(char* k, int s, Wierzcholek** &n, Wierzcholek* &nast , Wierzcholek* &poprz)
{
      //typowy wierzcholek grafu.
    klucz = k; sasiedztwo = s; sasiedzi = n;
    nastepny = nast; poprzedni = poprz;
}

 /*przeciazenia i metody*/
 //relacja rownowaznosci obiektow oparta na identycznosci kluczy
bool Wierzcholek::operator==(Wierzcholek const &prawy) const
{
    if ( klucz == prawy.klucz )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void Wierzcholek::okresl_ilosc_sasiadow(int n)
{
    delete [] sasiedzi;
    sasiedzi = new Wierzcholek* [n*sizeof(Wierzcholek)];
    sasiedztwo = n;
}

/*###########################################################*/
/*########################### GRAF ##########################*/
/*###########################################################*/

 /*konstruktor*/
Graf::Graf(void)
{
    pierwszy = ostatni = 0;
    rozmiar = 0;
}

 /*metody*/
void Graf::dodaj(Wierzcholek* w)
{
    if ( pierwszy != 0 )
    {
        w->poprzedni = ostatni;
        ostatni = w;
        ostatni->poprzedni->nastepny = ostatni;
    }
    else 
        pierwszy = ostatni = w;
    ostatni->pozycja = rozmiar++;
}

void Graf::wyswietl(void)
{
    using namespace std;
    Wierzcholek *n = pierwszy;
    for( int j=0; j < rozmiar; n = n->nastepny)
    {
        cout << n->klucz << " :";
        for( int i=0; i < n->sasiedztwo; i++ )
            cout << " " << n->sasiedzi[i]->klucz;
        cout << " ;\n";
        j++;
    } 
    return;
}

int Graf::podaj_rozmiar(void)
{
    return rozmiar;
}

Wierzcholek* Graf::odszukaj_dfs(char* &klucz)
{
    using namespace std;

      //tablica przyporzadkowujaca kazdemu kolejnemu wierzcholkowi grafu
      //binarna wartosc oznaczajaca fakt odwiedzenia wierzcholka przez algorytm.
    TabDyn<bool> odwiedzony;
    for(int i=0; i < rozmiar; i++) 
        odwiedzony.dodaj(0);

      //stos wierzcholkow sasiadujacych z juz odwiedzonymi wierzcholkami.
    Stos< Wierzcholek* > stos;
      //wierzcholek zdjety ze stosu.
    Wierzcholek* biezacy = pierwszy;
      //kolejny wierzcholek ciagu wierzcholkow grafu,
      //uwzgledniony, aby nie pominac wierzcholkow izolowanych.
    Wierzcholek* numerowany = pierwszy;
      //zmienna pomocnicza stworzona dla przejrzystosci kodu
      //wierzcholek sasiadujacy z biezacym
      //dokladany na stos, jezeli nie zostal jeszcze odwiedzony.
    Wierzcholek* sasiad = 0;

      //elementow grafu jest dokladnie "rozmiar".
    for( int i=0; i < rozmiar; i++, numerowany=numerowany->nastepny )
    {
cout << "plus: " << numerowany->klucz << endl;
        if( odwiedzony[numerowany->pozycja] )
            continue;
        stos.doloz( numerowany );
        while( !stos.jest_pusty() )
        {
            biezacy = stos.zdejmij();
            if ( odwiedzony[biezacy->pozycja] )
                continue;
            else
                odwiedzony[biezacy->pozycja] = true;
            if( strcmp(biezacy->klucz, klucz) == 0 )
            {
                cout << endl;
                return biezacy;
            }
              //sasiadow jest dokladnie "sasiedztwo".
            for( int j=0; j < biezacy->sasiedztwo; j++)
            {
                sasiad = biezacy->sasiedzi[j];
                if( !odwiedzony[sasiad->pozycja] )
                    stos.doloz(sasiad);
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the files for Stack (here as "Stos") and Dynamically Allocated Table (here as "TabDyn")

```
#ifndef STOS_H
#define STOS_H

template<typename T> class TabDyn;

template<typename T>
class Stos
{
private:
    /*pola*/
    TabDyn<T>* pula;

public:
    /*konstruktory*/
    Stos(void);
    Stos(int);
    ~Stos(void);
    /*metody*/
    void wyczysc(void);
    bool jest_pusty(void) const;
    T& top(void);
    T zdejmij(void);
    void doloz(const T&);
};

#include "Stos.tcc"

#endif



//Stos.tcc
#ifndef STOS_TCC
#define STOS_TCC

#include "TabDyn.h"

template<typename T>
Stos<T>::Stos(void)
{
    pula = new TabDyn<T>;
}

template<typename T>
Stos<T>::Stos(int rozmiar)
{
    pula = new TabDyn<T>(rozmiar);
}

template<typename T>
Stos<T>::~Stos(void)
{
    delete pula;
}

template<typename T>
void Stos<T>::wyczysc(void)
{
    pula->wyczysc();
}

template<typename T>
bool Stos<T>::jest_pusty(void) const
{
    return pula->jest_pusty();
}

template<typename T>
T& Stos<T>::top(void)
{
    return pula->koniec();
}

template<typename T>
T Stos<T>::zdejmij(void)
{
     //nalezy uprzednio sprawdzic czy stos nie jest pusty!
    T el = pula->koniec();
    pula->usun();
    return el;
}

template<typename T>
void Stos<T>::doloz(const T& el)
{
    pula->dodaj( el );    
}

#endif


//TabDyn.h
#ifndef TABDYN_H
#define TABDYN_H

using namespace std;

int const STD_ROZMIAR = 50;

/*###########################################################*/
template<typename T>
class TabDyn
{
private:
    /*pola*/
    int max_rozmiar;
    int akt_rozmiar;
    T *przydzial_pamieci;

public:
    /*metody*/
    TabDyn(int rozmiar = STD_ROZMIAR);
    T& operator[](int i);
     //usuwa stary przydzial pamieci i nadaje nowy
    bool zarezerwuj(int);
     //chyba: wyjebac stary przydzial i przydzielic nowy
    void wyczysc(void);
     //sprawdzic akt_rozmiar
    bool jest_pusty(void);
     //wskaznik na poczatek plus akt_rozmiar
    T& koniec(void);
    bool usun(void);        //!!! pop_back
     // void doloz_nkoniec( const T& ); //!!! push_back
    void dodaj( const T& ); //!!! push_back

};

#include "TabDyn.tcc"

#endif


//TabDyn.tcc
#ifndef TABDYN_TPP
#define TABDYN_TPP

#include <iostream>

/*###########################################################*/

template<typename T>
TabDyn<T>::TabDyn(int rozmiar)
{
    przydzial_pamieci = new T [rozmiar*sizeof(T)];
    max_rozmiar = rozmiar;
    akt_rozmiar = 0;
}

template<typename T>
T& TabDyn<T>::operator[](int i)
{
    if( i >= 0 && i < akt_rozmiar )
    {
        return *(przydzial_pamieci + i);
    }
    cout << "Blad: Zarzadano wartosci tablicy dynamicznej spoza zakresu. Podano wartosc ostatniego elementu.\n";
    return *(przydzial_pamieci + akt_rozmiar);

}

template<typename T>
bool TabDyn<T>::zarezerwuj(int wolumen)
{
    if ( max_rozmiar == wolumen )
        return true;
    if ( wolumen < akt_rozmiar )
    {
        cout << "Blad: Nowy zadany rozmiar tablicy dynamicznej nie jest w stanie pomiescic elementow, ktore juz sie w niej znajduja. Odmowa wykonania operacji. " << endl;
        return false;
    }
    T *npamiec = new T [wolumen*sizeof(T)];
    if ( ! jest_pusty() )
    {
        for( int i=0; i < akt_rozmiar; i++ )
        {
            *(npamiec + i) = *(przydzial_pamieci + i);
        }
    }

    max_rozmiar = wolumen;
    delete [] przydzial_pamieci;
    przydzial_pamieci = npamiec;
    return true;
}

template<typename T>
void TabDyn<T>::wyczysc(void)
{
    delete [] przydzial_pamieci;
    przydzial_pamieci = new T [max_rozmiar*sizeof(T)];
}

template<typename T>
bool TabDyn<T>::jest_pusty(void)
{
    return !akt_rozmiar;
}

  //zwraca ostatni element tablicy
template<typename T>
T& TabDyn<T>::koniec(void)
{
    T& ans = *(przydzial_pamieci + akt_rozmiar - 1);
    if( !akt_rozmiar )
        std::cout << "Blad, stos jest pusty.\n";
    return ans;
}

  //usuwa ostatni element tablicy
template<typename T>
bool TabDyn<T>::usun(void)
{
    if ( akt_rozmiar == 0 )
    {
        std::cout << "Blad: Nie mam co usunac.\n";
        return false;
    }
    akt_rozmiar--;
    return true;        
}

  //dodaje ostatni element tablicy
template<typename T>
void TabDyn<T>::dodaj( const T& el )
{
    if ( akt_rozmiar + 1 > max_rozmiar )
    {
        cout << "Uwaga: przekroczono rozmiar tablicy dynamicznej. Zostanie przydzielona nowa wielkosc." << endl;
        zarezerwuj(max_rozmiar+1);
    }
    *(przydzial_pamieci + akt_rozmiar++) = el;
}

#endif
```

Comment: This is the only question I've seen on SO where Google Translate has come up and offered to translate the code.

Comment: Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should identify (or at least isolate) the problem by using a debugger or print statements, and then come back with a more specific question (once you've narrowed it down to a 10-line [test-case](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: @chris: Haha I was just about to leave the same comment.

Comment: The fact that you posted so much code is bad enough, but the fact that it is not in English pretty much guarantees that most people will skip over this thread entirely.

Comment: I have no idea why segmentation fault appears, that is why I've put all of it. Probably I would solve it myself if I was able to detect "notorious" 10-lines. It appears at the end of the program execution so it could be anywhere. I wouldn't overestimate the language issue, these are just random tags here. And I think I made it clear which method is problematic and what it is about.

Comment: <my previous attempt at a comment had some nonsense in it...> What does poprosze_graf? Is it heap memory? And is it definitely a Graf*?

Comment: @SirPentor "wczytaj_nazwe_pliku" gets a proper filename either from commandline or explicitly stated by the user after being asked by the program to do so. The "poprosze_graf" then builds the actual graph from that file and returns a pointer to it.

Comment: And that pointer is heap-allocated? I'm focusing on that because right after you say this error occurs you delete that pointer, so it if isn't heap-allocated you could get in trouble.

Comment: @SirPentor: He said the error occurs at the very end of the program, and that everything occurs as expected (but gets the error in addition).  I think that means that "Do widzenia." is printed.

Comment: @SirPentor inside "poprosze_graf" I use new. I think everything is ok there since if I choose option 1 from my menu - "wyswietl" - to display my graph and then exit, I get no segmentation fault. | And yes, "Do widzenia" is printed.

Comment: @anonymous_infoholic: I think he's suggesting that `delete g;` can fail if memory near `g` is corrupt.  But then you probably wouldn't see that final "Do widzenia".

Comment: At this point you probably need something approaching a debugger.

Comment: @SirPentor I have never used a debugger before. I've just started gdb right now but don't understand the output at all. Which output should I post here to supply you with the info needed to help me out?

Comment: Can't help you @anonymous_infoholic. I don't use gdb (I do mostly windows) and that's really something that needs more communication than comments on a forum. Generally, you will want to determine the exact line at which it is failing and inspect the state of the program at that time. I know that's not a ton of help. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your program, destructors run for `static` and global objects.  I don't see any of either in your code, except of course for `cin` and `cout` that you use.  But you continue using both successfully, which suggests that you aren't trashing their memory with a wild pointer.

I would check whether you have any variables with static storage duration in other files you haven't shown, and look for buffer overruns affecting those objects.

If you have Linux, try `valgrind`.  It will catch most pointer errors.

Comment: @anonymous: You can use follow this simple tutorial for using valgrind: https://courseware.stanford.edu/pg/pages/view/82981/

Comment: I don't use any static variables. And thanks, I'm checking valgrind right now.

Comment: could you give me a hint what could I do possibly wrong with cin and cout? in addition - it seems that my usage of the variable token with cin in menu.cpp is faulty..

Comment: You are correct, your code with `token` is completely wrong, and overwriting random memory, which can definitely cause a segmentation fault, either at that point or later.  Try changing it to `std::string token;`, perhaps? (and `#include <string>`)